# SharePoint backwards compability and learning curve

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I recently was tasked to take over the development of a SharePoint 2007 product. I haven't worked with SharePoint at all before so I thought it would be fun to try something new.

Firstly I need to learn the basics of SharePoint. However the product runs on an older version (2007) and now I'm looking for courses to take. It also uses SharePoint MOSS. But hopefully/probably in the near future, we will upgrade to at least SharePoint 2010. Basically, my questions are:

1. I'm looking for SharePoint courses, but which version should I aim for? Of course I would mostly like to learn SharePoint 2013 since it is the newest version, but will I be able to work with a SP 2007 product then? Is the 2010 version better to learn in that case or do I need to step as far back as 2007? How much difference is there really regarding code structure and such without looking at new features?
2. Is migrating a SP 2007 product to SP 2010 a whole lot of work even if this particular site is kinda small? Not an easy question to answer but if someone could share their experience that would be great.